# Changing the sizes of a coloured square after pressing a button

Tags: java, user-interface

I have written this code however I am having trouble with one aspect I wish to code into it. I want to make the green square change size when I press one of the three buttons I have so when I press the button 'small' the square changes size to small e.g. 100 and when I press the button 'medium' it changes size to medium e.g. 400. This is my code so far:

```
package Lab2;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FilledFrame frame = new FilledFrame();

        frame.setVisible( true );

    }
}

class FilledFrame extends JFrame {

    int size = 400;

    public FilledFrame()
    {

        JButton butSmall = new JButton("Small");
        JButton butMedium = new JButton("Medium");
        JButton butLarge = new JButton("Large");
        JButton butMessage = new JButton("Say Hi");

        SquarePanel panel = new SquarePanel(this);
        JPanel butPanel = new JPanel();

        butPanel.add(butSmall);
        butPanel.add(butMedium);
        butPanel.add(butLarge);
        butPanel.add(butMessage);
        add(butPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setSize( size+100, size+100 ); } }

    class SquarePanel extends JPanel {
    FilledFrame theApp;

    SquarePanel(FilledFrame app)
    {
        theApp = app;
    }

    public void paintComponent ( Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect(20, 20, theApp.size, theApp.size);
    }
}

class buttonHandler implements ActionListener {
FilledFrame theApp;
int size;

public buttonHandler(FilledFrame app, int size) {

    theApp = app;
    this.size = size;

}


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
    theApp.setSize(this.size, this.size);

    }
}
```

Comment: You did not ask a question, really. Please tell us what is stopping you from achieving your goal.

Comment: Apologies. I am unsure on what needs to be done to change the size of the square after pressing the button and was looking for some advice or help on what I could possibly do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I don't see any event listeners for your buttons, I assume this is all the code you have. Your buttons will not do anything unless you tell them to do it. You need to add event listeners, and through that change the size and update the panel.

Example:

```
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            theApp.size = 200;
            frame.getContentPane().repaint();
            //OR frame.repaint();
        }
    });
```

EDIT:
The problem with using the button handler class is you would need to find which buttton was pressed, instead its easier to use the way I showed above. I edited the code above, try copy pasting to one of the buttons.

Comment: I have just added this into my code however it still doesn't change the size of the square its self. I know I have to refer to my 'SquarePanel' class and the 'app' variable however I'm unsure how to do so.    butSmall.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int size = 200;
            }
        });

Comment: Instead of int size, you need to use the size variabe set in the FilledFrame class, because that is what the paintcomponent method is using to determine the size of thr square. What you are doing is just setting a new variable called size to 200. Please accept my answer if this solves it.

Comment: Ah okay. How would I set the size variable located in the FilledFrame class. I know that the 'int size = 400' at the start of my code sets the size of the square however I'm unsure on how to get that size variable or call that variable within the ActionListener

Comment: Just to add further I have created a new class button handler which is shown above

Comment: Thank you for the response,I have added the code you wrote above however i'm getting errors on the lines 'theApp.size' and 'frame.getContentPane' where it says 'cannot resolve symbol'